# Using Apollo client wrapper in Next.js 14 App router

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am using Next.js 14 (App router) for my react project. I need to use Graphql. I also have the Apollo server set up. As a complete beginner, quite confused as to which directory to create which file. I have installed Apollo client and have
app\util\apolloClient.ts
So in order to wrap with Apollo provider, is it layout.js or page.js . I don't have 'src' folder.
Please advise.
Also, how do I get around getting the configuration for the graphql from json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the app router, you have to use the [@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support) package.

Just follow the setup instructions in the README, and make sure to use the `useSuspenseQuery` hook instead of the `useQuery` hook in your application to get the most out of SSR.